# jquery, unselect checkbox by value

Tags: jquery

i have many checkbox:

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_user" value = "1"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_user" value = "2"/>   
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_user" value = "3"/>
...
```

and checkbox with value 2 is selected. Is possible unselect checkbox (with jQuery) when i now only value.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
$("input:checkbox[value=2]").attr("checked", true);
```

Comment: Why do I never see you on SO? :)

Comment: I answer things 5 minutes before you, like a ninja.