# Checking a specific checkbox using JS

Tags: jquery, checkbox, attr, checked

I am looking to check a specific check box by calling its name. The name is c[featured_ad] and I will share what I've attempted below. Thanks for your help.

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
$('input:checkbox[name=c[featured_ad]]').attr('checked',true);
}
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="listing_extra_item">
<div class="listing_extra_cost price">$0.00 US</div>
<input name="c[featured_ad]" value="0" type="hidden">
<label>
<input name="c[featured_ad]" value="1" type="checkbox">
</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462344/jquery-unselect-checkbox-by-value

Comment: Anyone else have any ideas? So far, none have worked.

Comment: What are you getting in the console when you try to run the script?  Any errors?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="c[featured_ad]"]:checked').length > 0;
```

to check if there is any checkbox checked.

If you need to check a checkbox on document load, just use:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="c[featured_ad]"]').prop('checked', true);
```

**And most important of all remember that single quotes should be used where you want double quotes to appear inside the string without having to escape them, or vice versa.**

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/65adr/51/

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the name in quotes:

```
$('input:checkbox[name="c[featured_ad]"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

If you are on jQuery 1.6+ you should use .prop():

```
$('input:checkbox[name="c[featured_ad]"]').prop('checked', true);
```

Edit:

Apparently you need to escape the brackets:

$('input:checkbox[name="c\[featured_ad\]"]').prop('checked', true);

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly. Doesn't look like that worked.

Comment: Edited answer, try escaping [] with using double backslash.

Comment: Escaping didn't do it. I also tried it with both methods, .prop and .attr

Comment: Hmm, apparently stackoverflow escaped my escapes! so its \\ aka. backslashbackslash..

Comment: I attempted with double backslash and I am not successful. Check it out.

`$(document).ready(function(){
$('input:checkbox[name="c\\[featured_ad\\]"]').prop('checked', true);
  });`

We've gotta be close. These suggestions make sense and they're checking out in Fiddle too.

Answer (score 0):

Here try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/r6WLE/1/

**JS**

```
$("input[type='checkbox'][name='c[featured_ad]']").attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Also, close all the HTML tags, it's just a better practice.

Comment: Thanks but not working. I am adding the JS immediately before the closing </head>. I tried a quick alert( "welcome" ); and that worked like a charm.

Comment: Did you use document ready function and place it inside it ? Works fine on fiddle

Comment: I saw that it worked fine in Fiddle which makes this more perplexing. Originally, I had it run on window onload, I changed to document ready. How does this look? 

`<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
$("input[type='checkbox'][name='c[featured_ad]']").attr('checked', 'checked');
  });
</script>`

Comment: Did you include the js library ? Do you see any error in consoles ?